# Using mutiple keys to encrypt the same text with the password as a key but someone changes their password

Tags: encryption, php

I want to make a messaging social network but am worried about the NSA wiretapping all my members at once without merit like they wanted to do with Lavabit.

I've found a way to encrypt messages using multiple keys (one key for each user, so that multiple users can see the same message), and thought the best way to do so is to use the user's typed in password as a key which I salt and hash to compare to the salted and hashed version in the database to see if they match, as I don't have access to the password and it's personal to the user.

But what if someone changes their password? Then their password key won't be able to access their encrypted messages. What's the best way to go about this? It's not like I can store the key in the database.

Comment: Have you looked at technologies like PGP?

Comment: There's even multi-recipient support in that standard.

Comment: I can't use PGP because the encrypted private messages have multiple recipients. The messages are a part of chat rooms where multiple members will get to view it, so I need to encrypt the message with multiple keys at once, something PGP cannot do with one-two-one communication.

Answer (score 2):

> But what if someone changes their password? Then their password key
>   won't be able to access their encrypted messages. What's the best way
>   to go about this?

When someone changes their password, every system I am familiar with requires the user to type in both the old password and the new password.

### simple

If there is only a small amount of encrypted data, and you want your user to be able to access that data with only the new password, the simplest approach is to decrypt all that data with the old password to recover the plaintext, and then encrypt the plaintext using the new password.

### indirection

My understanding is that many systems have several levels of indirection.
When someone wants to read the plaintext of one document, behind the scenes what really happens is the typed-in password is used to decrypt a keyring that stores (in encrypted form) a master key.
(typically the "~/.ssh/id_rsa" file or the "~/Library/Keychains/" file).

The encrypted document is typically stored in RFC 4880 [OpenPGP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenPGP) Message Format or something similar.
The master key is used to decrypt one of the blocks in the header corresponding to that master key, giving the unique symmetric key used only for the body of this one document.
Then that symmetric key is used to decrypt the body of the encrypted document, producing the plaintext.

When someone changes to a new password, generally the old password is used decrypt the entire keyring, and then the system encrypts the keyring with the new password.
All the files are still accessible to that user, because the exact same master key is used to decrypt that file.

Alternatively, for each document the user has permission to access, one could add another block to the header of that encrypted file that contains an encrypted version of the same document-unique symmetric key, encrypted by a fresh new master key.

Ideally the user would carry around his own keyring and no one else would ever have access to it.
In practice, many systems store an (encrypted) keyring for each user.

Comment: I asked my friend how to do it before you posted your answer, and he said a much similar thing to what you said.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend two keys. Since all messages are encrypted with key A and therefore, if a user changes his key, all messages have to be re-encrypted (possibly a high workload) a different solution makes sense.

I would let the server generate an encryption-key A for each user which can be accessed by the users custom encryption-key key B. So if you choose your A strong enough all messages stay intact when the user changes his key. In this way all you need to do is update the has value to the encryption key and have a very low complexity.

Is this of use to you? If not, please let me know :)

John

Comment: Is key B different of every user or is it universal?

Comment: The server shouldn't ever have the encryption key so it can't generate it.

Comment: If the server shouldn't have the encryption key, do I decrypt the user's messages when they login? The private key has to be stored _somewhere_ so that the user's messages are decrypted when they login. I can't use the password because the user might change it, and I can't expect the user to enter a PIN each time they login, as it's not good UX.

Comment: @desbest - you need to decide whether you really want to be NSA-proof or not. If you have the keys server side, it means that the NSA can hack you to get the data. Even if you have a panic button to delete all keys, doing it successfully is very hard.

Comment: @Neil Smithline: Very good point. Maybe it would make more sense if the user has both keys with the same system as descibed above. But is not so clever either because you have to use two keys and if the encryption-key get compromised changing your pasword/key does not matter at all anymore.
I would never use a password as a key anyway, even salted it is not recommened. How is your structure, where are all messages stored and how have you implemented that many user can decrypt a message? Do you use group diffie hellman? Or have you found a symmetric solution?

Comment: I don't have a solution. I'm not sure the problem has a solution as specified.

Comment: I should have said that this part of the question was targeted at desbest, sorry for this.

Comment: I asked my friend and he figured out how to do it and told me, so now I know how to do it.

Comment: then I would suggest to share your information and maybe help others who experience the same question.